# Power BI - VALOR ACUMULADO CONFORME FILTRO COM VÁRIOS CRITÉRIOS

Tags: powerbi

Tenho um banco de dados de estoque com quatro colunas: Data - Produto - Entradas - Vendas.
1) A 1ª coluna contém as datas, todas elas sempre com o dia 01 do mês e ano: 01/01/2010 - 01/02/2010. As datas se iniciam em 01/01/2010 e vão até 01/11/2018.
As datas se repetem várias vezes em sequência, pois temos várias vendas no mesmo dia.
2) A 2ª coluna contém os nomes dos produtos, que é claro se repetem muitas e muitas vezes, inclusive no mesmo dia, pois há vendas diariamente.
3) A 3ª coluna tem os valores de entrada no estoque. Para cada produto há vários lançamentos durante os meses dos anos.
4) A 4ª coluna tem as saídas de cada venda realizada.
Preciso criar uma 5ª coluna, ou uma medida, para a cada linha retornar o valor acumulado levando em conta cada produto, entrada e saída.

---

Agrupei no Power Query por data conforme imagem. Ficou melhor desta maneira. Só falta o acumulado por linha conforme cada produto. Conforme imagem abaixo

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Paulo, esse acumulado seria a diferença entre entrada - saída?

Comment: Sim Clayton!
Diferença entre entrada e saída.
Cada linha é entrada ou saída.
Para cada data no formato dd/mm/aaaa pode ter várias linhas do mesmo dia, com principalmente várias saídas no mesmo dia de produtos repetidos, pois as compras são para diversas empresas.
As datas no formato dd/mm/aaaa foram todas transformadas no primeiro dia do mês ano de origem.

Comment: Sim. Várias saídas no mesmo dia de diversos produtos, e com produtos repetidos, pois as vendas são para várias empresas.

Comment: Tentou utilizar DAX?  Algo como criar uma medida utilizar a fórmula:   (SOMA(ENTRADAS) - SOMA(VENDA))

Comment: Tentei, mas não dá o resultado esperado.

Comment: Se puder alterar a pergunta adicionando os dados atuais (assim como fez na resposta que criou), e adicionar outra imagem com o resultado esperado ficaria mais facil então

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Agrupei no Power Query por data conforme imagem.
Ficou melhor desta maneira.
Só falta o acumulado por linha conforme cada produto.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode estar utilizando o SUM, para poder efetuar o acumulado por linha, criando uma nova coluna e adicionando SUM Vendas ou SUM entradas, e com isto será possível também ver o acumulado existem outras formas, mas creio que esta seja a mais rápida.

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).